# yui rowspan usage or alternative

Tags: yui, html-table

I have to do the following UI using YUI:
    In one pannel, I have the restaurant orders (One entry per order) . In another pannel, I need to show the order items associated with that order. I want to use rowspan so that, I can show the association side by side but I am not sure, whether it can be done using yui. Could you please help me with that.  If you feel, it can't be done in yui, Please recommend other options.
Thanks
Niraj

Comment: Do you mean YUI Dialog or Panel?